# Is it normal to have a high accuracy in the training from the beginning in keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am training a model that does image captioning. I noticed that my model get a very high training accuracy in the first epoch  ( around 89%)as well as the validation accuracy. Actually the training accuracy starts in a very high point from the beginning of the first epoch, it starts around %60 and goes up to %80 very fast. That does not make sense to me because the model learns very fast with a very high accuracy in the beginning.
  [Here is a screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSFBh.png)

Comment: How is your data distributed? Are your class distributions skewed?

Comment: Depends on the size of the model, the size of the dataset, and the difficulty of the dataset. A very large model will fit very quickly to a very small dataset. For example a CNN for image classification can fit to MNIST, a dataset of 60 000 training images within a few epochs with an accuracy of 90+%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mini-batches during fitting, you can watch the accuracy and loss change during each iteration. Your first few mini-batches will probably be terrible and then jump up around half-way through if the optimizer has found a reasonable local minimum. I've had this happen a lot; it depends a lot on which optimizer I use, the size of the model, and the amount of data. On its own, it isn't necessarily a bad thing. But be sure to check for over-fitting with a test set.